# Error in datetime with Oracle insert statement

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, datetime-format

I am writing an Oracle insert statement using Oracle SQL Developer tool, thus:

```
INSERT INTO  ITEMAPPROVAL ( REQUESTITEMID,  USERID,  APPROVALSTATUS,  REQUESTSTATUSID,  ITEMAPPROVALDATE,  ITEMAPPROVALNOTE , APPROVEDAMOUNT)  
                VALUES   ('132568', '15', '1', '4', TO_DATE('06/02/1436:10:6i:41a6', 'mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mi:ssam'), '' ,'20000');
```

on run always I have the following error

```
Error starting at line : 23 in command -
INSERT INTO  ITEMAPPROVAL ( REQUESTITEMID,  USERID,  APPROVALSTATUS,  REQUESTSTATUSID,  ITEMAPPROVALDATE,  ITEMAPPROVALNOTE , APPROVEDAMOUNT)  
                VALUES   ('132568', '15', '1', '4', TO_DATE('06/02/1436:10:6i:41am', 'mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mi:ssam'), '' ,'20000') 

    Error report -
        SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
        01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
        *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
                   the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
                   "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
                   with no extra whitespace.
        *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

I think error belongs to date format, I searched the web but without any hope.

**Update:**

The query generated from Visual Studio like that

```
query = "INSERT INTO  ITEMAPPROVAL " +
                               "          ( REQUESTITEMID,  USERID,  APPROVALSTATUS,  REQUESTSTATUSID,  ITEMAPPROVALDATE,  ITEMAPPROVALNOTE , APPROVEDAMOUNT) " +
                               " VALUES   ('" + itemapproval.RequestItemID + "', '" + itemapproval.User.ID + "', '" + itemapproval.status + "', '" + itemapproval.requeststatus.ID + "', TO_DATE('" + itemapproval.date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mi:ssam") + "', 'mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mi:ssam'), '" + itemapproval.notes + "' ,'" + itemapproval.ApprovedAmount + "'); "
```

Comment: erm TO_DATE('06/02/1436:10:6i:41a6'

Comment: Your date input?? What is 6i?

Comment: thanks Mitch and Maheswaran for quick reply, I got this date from dot net conversion like I wrote in the question update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MI in format means minute.. Hope you got it as month and i. I put it here as 10 for example.

Same as AM in format means am or pm.

```
INSERT INTO  ITEMAPPROVAL ( REQUESTITEMID,  USERID,  APPROVALSTATUS,  REQUESTSTATUSID,  ITEMAPPROVALDATE,  ITEMAPPROVALNOTE , APPROVEDAMOUNT)  
                VALUES   ('132568', '15', '1', '4', TO_DATE('06/02/1436:10:10:41am', 'mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mi:ssam'), '' ,'20000');
```

Try the below format String in .NET

```
mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss.tt
```

And it would be like,

```
query = "INSERT INTO  ITEMAPPROVAL " +
                               "          ( REQUESTITEMID,  USERID,  APPROVALSTATUS,  REQUESTSTATUSID,  ITEMAPPROVALDATE,  ITEMAPPROVALNOTE , APPROVEDAMOUNT) " +
                               " VALUES   ('" + itemapproval.RequestItemID + "', '" + itemapproval.User.ID + "', '" + itemapproval.status + "', '" + itemapproval.requeststatus.ID + "', TO_DATE('" + itemapproval.date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mi:ssam") + "', 'mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:sstt'), '" + itemapproval.notes + "' ,'" + itemapproval.ApprovedAmount + "'); "
```

.[NET reference on Date formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ttSpecifier)

Comment: do you mean that I change that 
itemapproval.date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mi:ssam")

to that itemapproval.date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss tt")